# Append packet to PCAP with Scapy got TCP Retransmission

Tags: python, tcp, wireshark, scapy

I append TCP packet to Pcap file with Scapy Python , but when I open the pcap file with Wireshark  I see

`TCP Retransmission`

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the packet you append doesn't look like a retransmission of data in an earlier packet in the capture.

If you don't think it looks like a retransmission, submit a bug on [the Wireshark issue list](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues) and attach the capture file to the bug, so the developers can determine what the issue is.

Comment: Why should Wireshark think that it's  look like a retransmission of data ?

Comment: If a previous TCP segment from {host1:port1} to {host2:port2} sent data with sequence numbers M through N, and your TCP packet sends data from {host1:port1} to {host2:port2} with a range of sequence numbers that overlaps that range (M through N, M+1 through N, M through N+2, etc.), then your TCP packet would look like a retransmission because it's retransmitting some of the bytes in the sequence number range M through N.